# searching a list of strings for integers

Tags: python, string

Given the following list of strings:

```
my_list = ['element0 123 321\n', 'element1 223 32221\n', 'element2 19823 328771\n', ... ]
```

how can I split each entry into a list of tuples:

```
[ (123, 321), (223, 32221), (19823, 328771), ... ]
```

In my other poor attempt, I managed to extract the numbers, but I encountered a problem, the element  placeholder also contains a number which this method includes! It also doesn't write to a `tuple`, rather a `list`.

```
numbers = list()

for s in my_list:
    for x in s: 
        if x.isdigit():
            numbers.append((x))
numbers
```

Comment: Should *negative* integers be included as well?

Comment: no, only positive integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can first build a regex that identifies *positive* integers:

```
from re import compile

INTEGER_REGEX = compile(r'\b\d+\b')
```

Here `\d` stands for *digit* (so `0`, `1`, etc.), `+` for *one or more*, and `\b` are *word boundaries*.

We can then use `INTEGER_REGEX.findall(some_string)` to identify all positive integers from the input. Now the only thing left to do is iterate through the elements of the list, and convert the output of `INTEGER_REGEX.findall(..)` to a tuple. We can do this with:

```
output = [tuple(INTEGER_REGEX.findall(l)) for l in my_list]
```

For your given sample data, this will produce:

```
>>> [tuple(INTEGER_REGEX.findall(l)) for l in my_list]
[('123', '321'), ('223', '32221'), ('19823', '328771')]
```

Note that digits that are not separate words will *not* be matched. For instance the `8` in `'see you l8er'` will not be matched, since it is *not* a word.

Comment: That is brilliant! Given me lots to learn, thank you for explaining the method too!

Answer (score 3):

your attempts iterates on each char of the string. You have to split the string according to blank. A task that `str.split` does flawlessly.

Also `numbers.append((x))` is `numbers.append(x)`. For a tuple of 1 element, add a comma before the closing parenthese. Even if that doesn't solve it either.

Now, the list seems to contain an id (skipped), then 2 integers as string, so why not splitting, zap the first token, and convert as tuple of integers?

```
my_list = ['element0 123 321\n', 'element1 223 32221\n', 'element2 19823 328771\n']

result = [tuple(map(int,x.split()[1:])) for x in my_list]

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[(123, 321), (223, 32221), (19823, 328771)]
```